# Change domain name on page load in source code with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, encoding

I was playing around with urls the other day and i was wondering if there is a way to for example substitute the domain name for a video link on page load
in the source code, while having the original link still interpreted by the browser to play the video correctly.

So for example, if i host an .mp4 on my server with following link:

```
    <source src="https://goofy.com/dogs.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="Low" res="360">
```

and i would like it to appear in the source code as:

```
    <source src="https://snoopy.com/dogs.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="Low" res="360">
```

but still having the goofy one played in the player, it it possible ?
(maybe with javascript ?)

What i am trying to achieve here doesn't need to be that advanced, when i meant "scrape" i was just thinking about people opening the inspector manually and simply grabbing the link, in my example:

```
https://goofy.com/dogs.mp4
```

So i was rather thinking of some simple javascript letter substitution scheme on pageload that would display some random letters instead of "goofy". Maybe something like this:

```
var chars = {'a':'b','c':'z','i':'e'};
var enc;
var str = "goofy.com"; 
window.onload = function() {
enc = str.replace(/[abc]/g, m => chars[m]);
alert(enc);
};
```

but i think it won't work, as the player will end up playing the url with the wrong domain name. An i'm not that good at javascript, so i'm not sure of what i'm doing either... Feel free to correct me or maybe offer some solution ? thanks.

Comment: What's your actual end goal? Its not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: How is it not clear ? The end goal is if someone scrapes my site for links, the result of his grab will be useless because the snoopy.com domain won't exist.

Comment: Its not clear, hence I asked. Now you've stated what you are actually trying to achieve vs your unclear original question. Now to answer the actual question, I'll leave an answer below.

Comment: I find it odd that the tooltip for downvoting here says "unclear or not useful".
The question i ask is useful to me, because i couldn't find an answer for it. I have difficulties to grasp the logic on how a legitimate question should look like or not look like. Little lost here, and no help yet. A bit discouraging if you ask me :(

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment reply, you want to obfuscate the source urls for a video file.

No, modifying the urls in the `<source/>` DOM elements won't do anything for you. A bot is getting the raw html from your site, so if the original source urls are embedded there you're not going to be able to hide anything.

Moving up the stack a bit, look at how Youtube handles structuring their urls. At its core, they have a js library that handles building out the video urls and video player dynamically at run time. While its highly obfuscated, its not a huge amount of work to discover what the actual video urls are and download them if you want. If someone really wants to get your videos, its not much work to either investigate the page with dev tools in the browser.

And going low-level, its arbitrary to run a packet sniffer like Charles proxy with a man in the middle local SSL proxy service (built in) to look at the requests being sent back and forth and to easily track down the source url that are delivering the video.

You could go back 10 years and try using Flash or some other embedded 3rd party plugin to "encrypt" the video stream but that's stupid and self defeating. If I *really* want your videos, I'll just play them full screen and record them on my computer.

Hopefully that more thoroughly answers your question.